# Disabling Design View in MS Access

Tags: ms-access

I'm trying to input some code that hides "Design View" as an option for our internal application unless a certain permission requirement is met.

The following code works with one exception:

```
On Error Resume Next
If Not GetUserInfo("ADMIN_PERMIS") = 1 Then
    Dim cb As CommandBar
    Dim cbCtl As CommandBarControl
    For Each cb In CommandBars
        If cb.type = msoBarTypePopup Then
            For Each cbCtl In cb.Controls
                If cbCtl.Caption = "&Design View" Then
                    cbCtl.enabled = True
                    cbCtl.visible = False
                Else
                    cbCtl.visible = True
                End If
            Next
        End If
    Next
    Set cb = Nothing: Set cbCtl = Nothing
End If
```

The one problem with this is that it disables Design View not only for the current database, but also for any other access database that is launched.  I'm looking for a way to try and apply this code in such a way that it only affects the Access database I have the code in and not in every single instance of it.

Comment: We moved away from ULS into Active Directory based security, specifically to be able to use an ACCDB and away from ULS so that users aren't forced to remember a second login.  We've considered doing compiled executable versions (accde's) but our frontend undergoes pretty constant development and it makes it difficult to debug and workaround if a time-sensitive problem arises.

Answer (score 4):

I recommend converting the database into a compiled, executable only .accde file (File --> Save & Publish --> Make ACCDE). Doing this will prevent any design or code changes in the application. Keep a development version in the normal .accdb format. Make your changes there and then compile into the .accde version for each update.

Since your team updates the database often, you could benefit from using Peter De Baets' [database starter](http://www.peterssoftware.com/aps.htm). The database starter makes a local copy of the front end of the database, allowing uses to continue to work while design changes are being made. After the production accde front end file is updated, the users will automatically copy the new file the next time they open the database. In my office I have found that I can push out a quick fix and simply email everyone saying "Close and reopen the database guys!".

Answer (score 0):

All these answers are great.  If you are interested in the simplest method, I found the form holds the key, albeit in a strange spot.

In the forms properties->Other Tab->Shortcut Menu =No

Comment: This method does not prevent a right click on the form's tab, where the menu is still available. It also deprives users from the benefit of filtering.