# MS Access - RIght-Click on object is disabled

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have recently taken a job that involves using an Access database to find information.  The database in question was built by a developer who left before it was completed.  He also didn't leave any documentation behind.

The database uses queries, forms, and VBA.  Some of the queries are no longer valid since the source data has a different format than what it was when the database was developed.  I know SQL and some basic VBA so I'm trying to modify the SQL; however, I cannot view the SQL behind the queries. I can't open it in Design View or SQL View.  I can't even right-click on any object.  Not only that but when I open an object, I can't right click on the top tab to close it.  There's a red x that populates on the top-right that I have to use.  I've tried holding shift when opening the DB, but it still happens.  I also went to: menu option Tools -> Startup -> to see if 'Allow Default ShortCut Menus' was unchecked; however, it wasn't.  I've checked other forums but haven't been able to find a solution.  I think it may be in the VBA somewhere but there are tons of modules and each module has a boat-load of sub procedures in it.  I have no idea what else it could be.  Any and all insight would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try searching the VBA code for `.AllowDesignChanges` and `.ShortcutMenu`.

Comment: Thank you for that tip.  I searched using "Current Project"  but unfortunately it didn't return a match for either property.

Comment: Hmmm... I'm pretty sure there's a way to disable the shortcut menus globally, but unfortunately it's not something I ever use so I'm not sure how to do it through the UI. Maybe search `.Visible = False` to see if you get hits on `CommandBars`?

Comment: Startup code is either called from a start form, or from an Autoexec macro. Make your way from there.

Comment: Perhaps this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15957315/disabling-design-view-in-ms-access

Comment: Thank you all so much! Andre and Comintern were both correct.  In the AutoExec proc there was a statement that disabled all CommandBars.

Answer (score 1):

@Andre and @Comintern both provided correct answers.  The culprit was in the Auto Exec function and it had a loop that went through each CommandBar and set Enabled = False.