# Is it possible to password protect Design view in MS Access? or through code?

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have searched for similar problems, but haven't got the answer I am looking for.

I am trying to **Disable the Design View** option present in Ribbon Toolbar in MS Access by using **VBA code**, so that users cant access it. I am using MS Access 2007.

I have tried the code provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15957315/disabling-design-view-in-ms-access), but that did not work for me.

I have also tried File->options method to remove the Design view from Ribbon. But with this step, user can get back the Design view with little surfing and hence not opting for this solution.

Is there any way to make the Design View **Password Protected** like how we do for code part?

Answer (score 0):

Open the Access program without a database

Now choose menu File -> Open

In the file open dialog box, bottom right, immediately to the left of the Cancel button, change the "Open" dropdown to "Open Exclusive"

Hold down the left Shift key so your startup code doesn't run

Now choose your database file, and click Open button (after you have already changed it's dropdown to "Open Exclusive")

NOw Click the "File" menu from under the Office 2013 ribbon.

There is a very large button that says "Encrypt with Password".

Click that and enter your secret database password.

After clicking "Ok" button close the database and re-open it.

Now nobody can change the form design (unless they know the password you have set)

Comment: Hi Mike, This creates password to protect code. I am looking for password protect on Design view, where we drag and drop the buttons and text boxes etc.

Comment: Convert the .accdb to an .accde which is encrypted internally and forms are non-editable (even by you, so keep the original .accdb for development and release the .accde to your end-users)

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple options to 'protect' the design view.  You can, as one comment suggests, deploy an accde version to your users - but that eliminates any possibility of accessing in the design view in the file, so if you have a user with a weird error, you have to deploy them the 'unlocked' accdb to find the issue.  Also, you need to compile an accde with the proper bit version that your users have for the accde to work.  For example, if you have a 32 bit version of access, but your users have a 64 bit (or reverse), the accde won't run.  So, I recommend blocking it out with the settings and some code.

I have put a 'security' function in place that I run before deploying my files - and i keep an 'unlocked' development copy on my machine, along with a 'unlocker' file that can programmatically 'unlock' the access file.  I have used this with 2010, 2013, 2016, and 365 - so i imagine it should work with 2007.

I am putting my code below, and if you have questions, please let me know.

Here is the code:

```
    Public Function UpdateDatabaseFileProperties( _
        sDatabaseFile As String _
        , bEnable As Boolean _
        ) As Boolean

    '   Error Direction
                                                        '
        On Error GoTo ErrorHandling
                                                        '
    '   Declare
                                                        '
        Dim AccObj As Access.Application
                                                        ' an array to hold the properties to change
        Dim arrProperty() As Variant
                                                        ' a counter to run through the permissions list
        Dim iCounter As Integer
                                                        '
    '   Set
                                                        ' an array of properties to change
        arrProperty = Array( _
            "StartupShowStatusBar" _
            , "AllowBuiltInToolbars" _
            , "StartupShowDBWindow" _
            , "AllowFullMenus" _
            , "AllowBreakIntoCode" _
            , "AllowSpecialKeys" _
            , "AllowByPassKey" _
            , "AllowShortcutMenus" _
            , "AllowDatasheetSchema" _
            )
                                                        ' set the access object
        SetAccessFileObject AccObj, sDatabaseFile, True, False, False
                                                        '
    '   Use Variables
                                                        '
        For iCounter = LBound(arrProperty) To UBound(arrProperty)
                                                        ' change the property of the database
            ChangeDatabaseProperty CStr(arrProperty(iCounter)), dbBoolean, bEnable, AccObj, True, False
                                                        ' go to the next property
        Next iCounter
                                                        ' set the navigation pane lock
        AccObj.DoCmd.LockNavigationPane bEnable
    ' close the file when complete
        CloseAccessDatabaseFile AccObj
                                                        '
    ExitCodeBlock:
                                                        '
    '   Clear Variables
                                                        '
        Exit Function
                                                        '
    '   Error Handling
                                                        '
    ErrorHandling:
                                                        '
        ErrorHandler Err.Number, Err.Description, lModuleID, 0
                                                        '
    End Function

Public Function ChangeDatabaseProperty( _
    sPropertyName As String _
    , vPropertyType As Variant _
    , vPropertyValue As Variant _
    , AccObj As Access.Application _
    , Optional bLeaveOpenAfterEdit As Boolean = False _
    , Optional bGiveUserControl As Boolean = False _
    ) As Boolean
                                                    '
'   Error Direction
                                                    '
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandling
                                                    '
'   Declare
                                                    '
    Dim dbs As DAO.Database
                                                    '
    Dim prp As DAO.Property
                                                    '
    'Dim AccObj As Access.Application
                                                    '
'   Set
                                                    ' set the database object
    Set dbs = AccObj.CurrentDb
                                                    '
'   Use Variables
                                                    ' set the property value
    dbs.Properties(sPropertyName).Value = vPropertyValue
                                                    ' if the file should not be left open after the changes are made
    If bLeaveOpenAfterEdit = False Then
                                                    ' quit the file and save all changes
        AccObj.Quit acQuitSaveAll
                                                    ' if the database file does not equal blank and it should be left open
    ElseIf bLeaveOpenAfterEdit = True And bGiveUserControl = True Then
                                                    ' provide control to the user
        AccObj.UserControl = True
        
        AccObj.Visible = True
                                                    '
    End If
                                                    '
ExitCodeBlock:
                                                    '
'   Clear Variables
                                                    '
    Set dbs = Nothing
                                                    '
    Set prp = Nothing
    
    If bLeaveOpenAfterEdit = False Then
                                                    '
        Set AccObj = Nothing
    
    End If
                                                    '
    Exit Function
                                                    '
'   Error Handling
                                                    '
ErrorHandling:
                                                    ' depending on the error experienced
    Select Case Err.Number
                                                    ' 3270 = property does not exist
        Case 3270
                                                    '
            Set prp = dbs.CreateProperty(sPropertyName, vPropertyType, vPropertyValue)
                                                    '
            dbs.Properties.Append prp
                                                    '
            Resume Next
                                                    ' in any other error
        Case Else
                                                    '
            ErrorHandler Err.Number, Err.Description, lModuleID, 0
                                                    '
            Resume ExitCodeBlock
                                                    '
    End Select
                                                    '
End Function
```